# EaselJS onPress not working on IPAD

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs

I have an Ipad web app I created using easelJS. I am getting the following error in the debug console on my IPAD when I press the element that is using "onPress".

**An error has occurred. This is most likely due to security restrictions on reading canvas pixel data with local or cross-domain images.**

This works on my desktop but when I visit site on my IPad it does not work. I am not using any external images(all images are local to my site) They are SVG images if that helps.

Comment: Found an answer. It seems that WebKit taints the canvas when using SVG. Nothing to do but move to PNGs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webkit taints the canvas when using SVG. Best bet is to use PNG.